# Get enviroment variable from string with ash

Tags: bash, environment-variables, ash

Consider the following:

```
/ # echo $TEMPLATEGO_SERVICE_HOST
192.168.1.1
/ # export string="TEMPLATEGO_SERVICE_HOST"
/ # echo $string
TEMPLATEGO_SERVICE_HOST
```

With bash I can do:

```
/ echo ${!string}
192.168.1.1
```

If I try the same with ash, I get the following error:

```
/ # echo ${!string}
ash: syntax error: bad substitution
```

I am running inside a alpine container and as a workaround I am downloading bash and using it. But want to avoid the extra size on my docker image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this in `ash` is to use `eval`. However, you should verify that what you are trying to evaluate consists *only* of a valid shell identifier to avoid executing unintended code from an untrusted value. For example,

```
if echo "$string" | grep -q '^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$' "$string"; then
    eval echo \$$string
fi
```